# Have a default pre value in a multicite

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using the `biblatex` package and I am trying to modify the `\cites` command.

The `\cites` command is defined as

```
\cites(<pre>)(<post>)[<pre>][<post>]{<key>}...[<pre>][<post>]{<key>}
```

I'll add some indexes to clarifiy what I'm trying to do.

```
\cites(<pre_0>)(<post_0>)[<pre_1>][<post_1>]{<key_1>}...[<pre_n>][<post_n>]{<key_n>}
```

`pre_0` will be shown preceding the multicite and `post_0` will be shown at the end.

I am trying to write a new command, that behaves exactly like `\cites` does, with the difference that `pre_1` to `pre_n` are filled with a default value.

All I achieved until now is to use a default value for `pre_0` using

```
\newcommand{\compares}{\cites[Cf. ]}
```

but I don't need to use `pre_0`. If it were an optional paramter to my new command, it would be nice, but it's not a must.

I was able to do this for the `\cite` command like this(`Cf.` is the default):

```
\newcommand{\compare}[2][]{\cite[Cf.][#1]{#2}}
```

Now I'd like to have the same behaviour for the `\cites` command. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am only starting to learn how to beat on `biblatex`. In general, you are trying to declare a new multicite command. For the `numeric` style the `\cites` is defined by

```
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\cites}[\mkbibbrackets]{\cite}{\multicitedelim}
```

so we want

```
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\mycites}[\mkbibbrackets]{\mycite}{\multicitedelim}
```

We now need to define `\mycite` to do what we want. Again starting from teh original `numeric` style

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

we can go to

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{myprenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{mypostnote}}
```

leaving us to define `\myprenote` and `\mypostnote`. The originals are defined in `biblatex.def` as

```
\newbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\newbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\setunit{\postnotedelim}%
     \printfield{postnote}}}
```

This is where I am not exactly sure what is best. One solution is

```
\newbibmacro*{myprenote}{x\space}
\newbibmacro*{mypostnote}{, y}
```

where `x` and `y` are whatever you want them to be. I don't think this is really the `bibltex` way and I think slightly better is

```
\newbibmacro*{myprenote}{\printtext{x}\setunit{\prenotedelim}}
\newbibmacro*{mypostnote}{\printtext{\addcomma\space y}\setunit{\postnotedelim}}
```

but I don't really understand what this is doing and I think we should be using field formatting. Putting it all together

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\newbibmacro*{myprenote}{\printtext[prenote]{x}\setunit{\prenotedelim}}
\newbibmacro*{mypostnote}{\printtext[postnote]{\addcomma\space y}\setunit{\postnotedelim}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\mycite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{myprenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{mypostnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\mycites}[\mkbibbrackets]{\mycite}{\multicitedelim}

\begin{document}
\cites(a)(b)[x][y]{angenendt}[x][y]{bertram}

\mycites(a)(b){angenendt}{bertram}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, looks very promising! I'll give it a try. I won't forget to accept it, if it is my road to success ;) Thank you!!

Comment: +1 This is the right idea. To make the definition easier try, say: `\newrobustcmd*{\cfautocites}{\AtNextCite{\renewbibmacro*{multiprenote}{\bibstring{confer}\prenotedelim}}\autocites}`. This approach should work for any citation command, except maybe `\textcites` from the verbose styles.

Comment: @Audrey thank you for the vote of encouragement, but your comment/answer doesn't seem to match my answer at all. If you get a chance I would love to see you expand it into an answer.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub All you really do in defining `\mycite` is take `\cite` and use different `prenote` and `postnote` macros. My suggestion takes the same approach, but hooks in the redefinition with `\AtNextCite`.

Answer (score 8):

The `\AtNextCite` hook allows you to easily define variants of existing citation commands.

```
\newrobustcmd*{\mycite}{\AtNextCite{<code>}\cite}
```

In `<code>` you can modify biblatex counters, generic commands, bibliography macros or formatting directives. These changes are applied only to the following `\cite`. Citation argument parsing can be left to biblatex. A mulitcite variant of `\mycite` can be defined similarly:

```
\newrobustcmd*{\mycites}{\AtNextCite{<code>}\cites}
```

Here's an example addressing your question. In the new citation commands you can override the default prenote `\bibstring{confer}` by providing a non-empty prenote argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose,maxnames=1]{biblatex}

\newrobustcmd*{\cfautocite}{\cfcitehook\autocite}
\newrobustcmd*{\Cftextcite}{\cfcitehook\Textcite}
\newrobustcmd*{\cfautocites}{\cfcitehook\autocites}
\newrobustcmd*{\Cftextcites}{\cfcitehook\Textcites}

\newrobustcmd*{\cfcitehook}{%
  \AtNextCite{\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{\usebibmacro{prenote:confer}}}}

\newbibmacro*{prenote:confer}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {\bibstring{confer}}
    {\printfield{prenote}}%
  \setunit{\prenotedelim}}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash #1}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
\cmd{Textcite}: \Textcite[e.g.][10]{companion} showed that... \\
\cmd{autocite}: Filler text \autocite[10]{companion,knuth:ct:a}. \\
\cmd{Textcites}: \Textcites[10]{companion}[e.g.][]{knuth:ct:a}{glashow} showed that... \\
\cmd{autocites}: Filler text \autocites[10]{companion}[e.g.][]{knuth:ct:a}{glashow}. \\\\
\cmd{Cfextcite}: \Cftextcite[e.g.][10]{companion} showed that... \\
\cmd{cfautocite}: Filler text \cfautocite[10]{companion,knuth:ct:a}. \\
\cmd{Cftextcites}: \Cftextcites[10]{companion}[e.g.][]{knuth:ct:a}{glashow} showed that...\\
\cmd{cfautocites}: Filler text \cfautocites[10]{companion}[e.g.][]{knuth:ct:a}{glashow}.
\end{document}
```

The same approach works for `multiprenote` - a field that can't be accessed via `\DeclareCiteCommand` or `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand`.

```
\newrobustcmd*{\cfmulticitehook}{%
  \AtNextCite{\renewbibmacro*{multiprenote}{\usebibmacro{multiprenote:confer}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{multiprenote:confer}{%
  \iffieldundef{multiprenote}
    {\bibstring{confer}}
    {\printfield{multiprenote}}%
  \setunit{\prenotedelim}}
```